# Как грамотно организовать поддержку языков для приложения Server (RESTFULL) —?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, локализация

Пришёл за советом архитекторов и людей, которые реализовывали похожу задачу, энтузиастов.

Есть задача по интернационализации приложения с архитектурой Сервер (RESTFULL API) -> Клиенты (WEB, Mobile, Desktop).

**Цель**: внедрить поддержку языковых пакетов.

**Вопрос**: каким образом это сделать ? 
1) На клиентах или сервере ? 
2) Отдавать сервером уже готовые данные с нужным переводи или отдавать коды для перевода на клиентах ? 
3) способы хранения таких структур данных. (Это лучше в JSON, PO, TXT) ?

P.S Клиентов может быть много.
***Это все должно легко поддерживаться и расширяться.***

**Стек технологий**: 
Клиенты: JS, JSON
Сервер: NodeJS, MongoDb + Redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делать локализацию придётся и на сервере, и на клиенте. На разных клиентах локализация может быть выполнена разными способами.

Например, мобильные приложения на Android удобно локализовывать с помощью встроенных средств. Серверные веб-приложения на Node.js, PHP, ASP.NET локализуются одним способом, а SPA — другим. Не смотря на свою *серверность* веб-приложения остаются клиентом для REST-сервисов.

Казалось бы, достаточно локализовывать только клиентский код, а с сервера всё присылать на английском языке. Это могло бы сработать для фиксированных данных. Если REST-сервис развивается и постоянно возвращает новые фразы в сообщениях об ошибках, или в серверных справочниках, то приходится дописывать множество клиентов одновременно.

Поэтому логично локализовывать не только клиентов, но и REST-сервер. Физически это делается через заполнение HTTP-заголовка [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Accept-Language) на клиентах.

Опыт показывает, что *легко поддерживаться и расширяться* такое решение может только в случае, если вы прикладываете серьёзные организационные усилия. Из собственного опыта могу рассказать о двух тонкостях.

Первая достаточно очевидна, но на всякий случай напишу. Если по какой-то причине вы не можете найти перевод в словаре, не завершайте выполнение с ошибкой — отправляйте оригинал фразы на английском языке.

Вторая не очень очевидна. Для корректного перевода вам не нужен не только текст, но и контекст. В нашем проекты были *заказы* и *смены*, и те и другие могли быть *закрыты*. Без контекста мы пытались перевести на русский язык слово *closed*, но на русском языке его род зависит от рода подлежащего. Заказ — *закрыт*, но смена — *закрыта*. У нас что-нибудь получалось нерпавильно: смена закрыт или заказ закрыта. Чтобы с этим справиться, мы стали присылать для перевода не только слово *closed*, но и контекст *order* или *shift* — как строку.

Фрагмент нашего словаря в формате JSON выглядит так:

```js
{
  . . .
  "License Classes": "Классы транспортных средств",
  "License Country": "Страна, выдавшая права",
  "[DriverProfile]License Number": "Номер водительского удостоверения",
  "[DriverProfile]License Start Date": "Дата выдачи удостоверения",
  "[DriverProfile]License End Date": "Срок действия удостоверения",
  "[VehicleProfile]License Number": "Номер лицензии",
  "[VehicleProfile]License Start Date": "Дата выдачи лицензии",
  "[VehicleProfile]License End Date": "Срок действия лицензии",
  . . .
}
```

Контекст в квадратных скобках.

В целом, задача перевода вполне разрешима и даже поддаётся некоторой автоматизации, но простого решения она не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо! очень кстатии, я заметил что контекст выполнен в линейной структуре, почему не в виде дерева в JSON формате... тем более что сервер что клиенты JS

Comment: @BrainStorm это просто способ хранения словаря (или хеш-таблицы). Для *Closed* с контекстом *Order* ищем сначала *[Order]Closed* и если не нашли, то просто *Closed*. Производительность решения O(1).

Comment: Понял! Спасибо большое!